# Find the number of substrings of a string which can be divisible by a number k

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, algorithm, math

given a string, I want to find all the sub-strings which can be formed from the original string which are divisible by an integer k. For example the string 14917 can form 7 sub-strings which are divisible by the integer 7. The sub-strings are: 14, 1491, 14917, 49, 91, 917 and 7. I have come up with a solution but it does not run efficiently when a large string is inputted. My code is

```
string = '14917'
divider = 7

count = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(string)+1):
        sub_string = string[i:j]
        if int(sub_string) % divider == 0:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

I have read about fast approaches for this kind of a problem, most of which talked about computing the rolling remainders of the string but I could not really implement it correctly. Is there any way in which this problem can be solved quickly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that you will conceptually get much more efficient than this. E.g., for the divisor 7, the decimal system does not have any nice structures that you could use for incremental calculations. The only thing I see that could potentially be improved is the number parsing stuff.

Comment: Do you want to find the strings, or count them?  (Hint: counting is faster.)

Comment: I agree with Nico. Removing the string operations from the body of the loop will speed up the code (but won't change the time complexity). In other words, convert the string to a list of digits *before* the loop.

Comment: because the number of subsets is 2^n

Comment: how big can k be?

Comment: You could avoid any modulo calculations by using a 10 * (k - 1) sized look-up table; I'm not sure how much real-world advantage that would give. But some values of k obviously have quick solutions, e.g. when k divides 10 or 100 or 1000...

Comment: The size of k ranges from 1 to 10. and the string ranges from 1 to 10000000

Comment: btilly, I just want to find the number of substrings (count them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an outline of how to solve this problem if we *just* want the count, we don't mind that there are multiple ways of pulling the same substring out, and `k` is relatively prime to `10` (which `7` is).

First let's go from the last digit of our number to the first, keeping track of the remainder of the whole number.  In the case of `14917` that means compiling the following table:

```
number  10**digits % 7   digit  remainder
                                          0
     7         1           7     0+1*7 -> 0
    17         3           1     0+3*1 -> 3
   917         2           9     3+2*9 -> 0
  4917         6           4     0+6*4 -> 3
 14917         4           1     3+4*1 -> 0
```

Now here is the trick.  Whenever you see the same remainder in two places, then from one to the other you've got something divisible by 7.  So, for example, between the two 3's you get 49.  If a particular value appears `i` times, then that represents `i*(i-1)/2` (possibly identical) substrings that are divisible by 7.

If we want to get unique substrings, then we have to do a *lot* more work.  But we can still be `O(length of string)` if we generate a suffix tree so that we can count the duplicates relatively quickly.

To actually produce the numbers, this approach will still be `O(n^2)`.  But it will be faster than your existing approach for large strings because you're only ever doing math with small integers.  Converting to/from strings to numbers that are thousands of digits long is not particularly fast...

---

So here is more detail on the complications of the suffix tree approach for count of unique substrings.  It is a lot harder to get right.

Above we proceeded from the end of the string back to the beginning, keeping track of the final remainder.  But this means that what a particular digit adds to the remainder depends on its position in the string.  However in a tree a given node is at different height's from the ends of the string.  This makes the remainder at a particular node harder to calculate.

What we need to do is calculate some sort of remainder where the contribution of the current digit depends on its height, to instead keep the contribution of the current digit fixed.  The trick to that is to multiply the set of possible remainders bubbling up by `10-1` instead. Then we'll get 0s if and only if the number starting here is divisible by `k`.  What does `10-1 (mod k)` mean?  It means a number `m` such that `(10*m) % k` is `1`.  It can be seen by inspection that `5` works for `7` because `50 = 7*7 + 1`.  We can always find the inverse with trial and error.  In general its existence and value can be more efficiently determined through [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).  Either way, in our case it is `5`.

Now it is more work to multiply the set of remainders by a number instead of the current digit, but it has the advantage that doing this we can merge branches of a tree.  Consider, for example, a suffix tree for  `5271756`.  (Note that uniqueness matters because the string `7` appears twice.)

```
(root):
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
(a): '17'
  f
(b): '27'
  a
(c): '5'
  b
  e
(d): '7'
  a
  f
(e): '6'(end)
(f): '5'
  e
```

Now we can work our way back up the tree finding counts of remainders.  The calculation for 756 illustrates the idea:

```
digit  prev_remainders remainders
#                 for    6
6      {}              {(6)%7: 1}
#                 for    5         56
5      {6: 1}          {(5)%7: 1, (5+5*6)%7: 1}
                       {    5: 1,         0: 1} = {0:1, 5:1}
#                 for    7         756           75
7      {0: 1, 2:1}     {(7)%7: 1, (7+5*0)%7: 1, (7+5*5): 1}
                       {    0: 1,         0: 1,       4: 1} = {0:2, 4:1}
```

And so at that point we have 2 strings divisible by 0 starting there, namely `7` and `756`.

Filling out the whole tree starting from the root and bubbling back in the same way (done by hand, I could make mistakes - and made a lot of them the first time around!):

```
(root): {0:8, 1:6, 2:3, 4:1, 5:4, 6:4}
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
(a): '17' {0:1, 1:3}
  f
(b): '27' {2:3, 6:3}
  a
(c): '5' {0:4, 1:3, 5:1}
  b
  e
(d): '7' {0:3, 4:1, 5:3}
  a
  f
(e): '6'(end) {6:1}
(f): '5' {0:1, 5:1}
  e
```

From which we conclude that there are `8` substrings divisible by `7`.  In fact they are:

```
175 (af)
5271 (cba)
52717 (cbaf)
5271756 (cbafe)
56 (ce)
7 (d)
7175 (daf)
756 (dcf)
```

What about the rest?  What does it mean that, for example, there are `3` ways of getting `2`?  It means that there are `3` substrings `s` such that `( (s%7) * (5^(len(s)-1)) ) %7 == 2`.  So we didn't need that in our final answer, but we certainly did in the intermediate calculations!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I just want to ask about the suffix tree. Since in my case I need to find all unique sub-strings so I might need to check for duplicates. What is the optimal strategy for building the suffix tree?

Comment: @SiddhantDube The standard approach is called [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).  But the calculation will get tricky.  I'll think about the details and add a note.

Comment: @SiddhantDube It was harder than I thought, but I gave an explanation of the principle.  You will definitely want to work out a few toy examples before writing general code because it is somewhat complicated.